# WordPress : troubles overriding a pluggable function in a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having issues overriding the `is_user_logged_in()` pluggable function in my first pluggin ever.
This function in pluggable.php is wrapped inside `if ( !function_exists('...') )` so I was expecting my version of the function to be executed without any problems but it doesn't seem to be the case.

```
new session_auth();

class session_auth{

    public $sessionUSERNAME; // php session variable for username

    public function __construct() {

        $this->sessionUSERNAME = $_SESSION['simple_auth']['username']; // php session variable for username

        add_filter('is_user_logged_in', array($this, 'is_user_logged_in'), 20);
        add_filter('wp_title', array($this, 'wp_title'), 20) ;

    }

    function is_user_logged_in() {
        return true;
    }

    public function wp_title($title)
    {
        return $title .'if this is displayed, the plugin is activated';
    }

}
```

My version of `wp_title` is successfully being executed instead of WordPress's one, but not my version of `is_user_logged_in`. I am not getting any errors.

What am I doing wrong in this script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `filter` for `is_user_logged_in`, as can be seen from the Wordpress pluggable.php code:

`function is_user_logged_in() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    return $user->exists();
}`

You need to create a `is_user_logged_in()` function in your file, and not put it inside a class. So, just put somewhere in your plugin (again, NOT inside class):

```
function is_user_logged_in() {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I may have misunderstood why/how filters work. However why can't I put it inside a class ? For this specific function it is not requiered, but having some of pluggable.php functions of my plugin inside a class would have been really helpful. Is there a way to make this work inside a class ? Either ways, thank you !

Comment: I don't think that will ever work, as the functions in the class belong to the class. This post deals with similar issue: https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/issues/332. Anyway, glad to help!

Comment: Okay, I will work around this then. Last thing, what is the difference between `wp_title` working if I put it inside a class, while this not being possible with `is_user_logged_in` ?

Comment: In the `wp_title()` function https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1090 close to end there's `$title = apply_filters( 'wp_title', $title, $sep, $seplocation );`. This is the filter. There's no such filter in `is_user_logged_in()`

Comment: Okay thanks ! So a filter is requiered for a function in order to be called in a class.

Comment: No, the filter is required inside and outside of class, in the way you wrote the code. You just mixed two things - pluggable function and a filter.